# Xamaring.Forms Android 8.0 - Visual Studio 2019

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm becoming crazy. I want to compile Xamarin.Forms for Android 8.0 with Visual Studio 2019
I setup all correct, I think, but I always get:

```
Error       The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for App_test32.Android (v8.0) is less than the minimum required $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Xamarin.Forms (8.1). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for App_test32.Android. App_test32.Android
```

Comment: Please open Android project propertise(right click your xxx.Droid project in VS, choose the `propertise` tab), then set the TargetFramework to the Android 8.1  like following screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/VGJKD9q After set it, please rebuild your project.

Comment: Yes, but in this way the APP crash on Android 8.0. Is it not possible to develop an APP for Android 8.0 by Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: You can develop app for Android 8.0, please update all of your nuget packages to the latest. Can you share a demo about app crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot **target** *8.0* and that's for a reason. Starting from **August 1, 2019** Google doesn't accept new apps that doesn't have targetSdkVersion set **below Android 9.0** (for new apps).

You can read more about this [here (Meet Google Play's target API level requirement)](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk) and more specifically [here (Target API level requirements for the Play Console)](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469#targetsdk).

If you open the second link, you will see that the targetSdkVersion will be bumped even to Android 10, starting from **August 3, 2020** (for new apps)

This is what you are seeing - Xamarin has restricted this, so that you don't set it lower that what it **must** be. Otherwise, you will be able to build it, but you won't be able to upload it. You can see the minimum version set [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/.nuspec/Xamarin.Forms.targets#L178)

However, you can still set it to 8.0, but you will need to downgrade the Xamarin.Forms & Xamarin.Android to a version that is way back - probably even before 4.0. This way you will be able to build the project, but the end result will be the same - you won't be able to upload the app to the PlayStore.

Useful link to get familiar with the difference between `Target Framework`, `Minimum Android Version` & `Target Android Version` from the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/android-api-levels?)

Here is the most important comparison:

> **Minimum Android Version <= Target Android Version <= Target Framework**

To sum up, I will quote again the guys from Microsoft (see in the link above):

> We recommend that you explicitly set the Target Android version to the latest version of Android that you use to test your app. Ideally, it should be set to the latest Android SDK version – this allows you to use new APIs prior to working through the behavior changes. For most developers, we do not recommend setting the Target Android version to Use Compile using SDK version.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! 
Now, everything is clear! 
That's meaning cutting a lot of users! But if they decided so.
In this case, It is a must to have a web APP next to the traditional one.

Comment: I think that you may have misunderstand the APIs terminology. No one is cutting a lot of users. The apps can still be deployed to Android phones with Android 8 (and below). Please read again the official docs to see the difference between Minimum Android Version and Target Framework. You can have Target Framework of Android 10 and still deploy to Android 5, if the Minimum Version supports it.

Also, if my post answers your question, mark it with a check mark so that others can see the solution to your problem.

Comment: Since you are new to community - it's a good practice when someone answers your question to accept it (check mark under the voting panel). That way he is awarded and helps others with similar issue to find faster the correct answer :)