# TargetFrameworkVersion with Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

This may sound like a stupid question (yes :) ) , but I'm learning.

I would like to create an application in Visual Community/Xamarin to display a simple hello. The technical constraint is that I'd like to develop it to test it on an Android 4.4
Everything is installed correctly, the emulator works but when I want to launch the application (F5), I get the following message :

> Gravité   Code    Description Projet  Fichier Ligne   État de la suppression
>   Erreur        The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Hi.Android (v4.4) is less
>   than the minimum required $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Xamarin.Forms
>   (8.1). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for
>   Hi.Android.   Hi.Android

The project is set as follow :

- Compile with : Android 4.4
- Minimal Android Version : 4.4
- Targetted Android : 4.4
- Xamarin.Forms (4.6.0.800)
- Xamarin.Essentials (1.5.3.2)

Any idea?

Comment: You should change your target Android to the version supported by the version of Xamarin.Forms you are using.

Comment: Xamarin.Forms requires that you compile with its matching Xamarin.Android version, so the version of Forms you are using, set your TargetFrameworkVersion to 8.1. You can still deploy/test on API 4.4, but you have to compile it w/ 8.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xamaring.Forms Android 8.0 - Visual Studio 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61608351/xamaring-forms-android-8-0-visual-studio-2019)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Android Versions in your Project Properties as followng:

```
Compile using Android Version : Latest Available Andriod Version in your environment (must be above Android 8.1)

Minimal Android Version : 4.4

Target Android Version: Latest Available Andriod Version in your environment (must be above Android 8.1)
```

Visual Studio will install the SDK for selected API version automatically if not installed. this will resolve your above mentioned problem

Comment: He is dealing with a Xamarin.Android TargetFrameworkVersion issue, not an Android API level issue (or missing Android APIs)

Comment: Correct, Target Android version(Target Framework) can not be less than Android version 8.1(Android API 27)

Comment: And that has nothing to do with a missing "SDK" and the "Target Framework" in the Android manifest is not the same as TargetFrameworkVersion (which is used at compile time)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your quick answer; really thanks

I've understand now (even if it's not completely clear for me)

I've change my settings as follow and work perfectly

Compile with : **Android 8.1 (Oreo)**
Minimal Android Version : 4.4
Targetted Android : 4.4
Xamarin.Forms (4.6.0.800)
Xamarin.Essentials (1.5.3.2)